# How do i acces a variable from another method?

Tags: java, variables

I want to access `this.s` variable from `actionPerformed` method and use it in `addSignTag` method. 
How do i do that? Sorry for reposting!

```
 String s;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    int index = 0;

    int connectorCoorX = MyGraphics.prevX;
    int connectorCoorY = MyGraphics.prevY; 
    Way w = new Way();

    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Check")){ 

        index = list.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("Index selected" + index);
        this.s= (String) list.getSelectedValue();
        System.out.println("Value Selected " +this.s);
        createMap();
    }
}


public void addSignTag(Way w, String tagKey, String valueKey)

{   String key = Tag.removeWhiteSpaces(tagKey);
    String value = Tag.removeWhiteSpaces(valueKey);

    if (key.isEmpty() || value.isEmpty())
        return;


}
```

Comment: method `addSignTag` should accept an **instance** of the object in order to have access to the (public) property `s`. Since `aaddSignTag` is a static method it cannot access instance properties without an instance

Comment: Thanks, Nikos M! Works! :)

Comment: @bmargulies, this question **is not duplicate** of that question

Comment: "Sorry for reposting!"